# Replacing the standard behaviour of the delete line hotkey "dd" in Ace editor's Vim mode with a function call

Tags: javascript, codemirror, ace-editor

My goal is to change the behaviour such that all vim commands that delete an entire line or several lines call a specific function instead.

This is my most recent try:

```
import * as ace from 'ace-builds';
this.aceEditor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
ace.require('ace/keybindings/vim');
this.aceEditor.setKeyboardHandler('ace/keyboard/vim');

ace.config.loadModule('ace/keyboard/vim', () => {
  var VimApi = ace.require('ace/keyboard/vim').CodeMirror.Vim;
  VimApi.defineEx('delete', 'd', this.deleteCurrentLineIfSolved.bind(this));
});
```

I have also tried using the mapCommand(), unmap() and map() functions.

The command in question appears to be defined starting on line 2352 of this repository:
https://github.com/replit/codemirror-vim/blob/master/src/vim.js
But I do not fully understand its inner workings.

Changing the 'delete' 'd' key does not appear to do anything. I am unsure how to specifically target specific hotkeys such as 'd' 'd' for deleting lines.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The actual repository of the ace editor is https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace and the file is https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/src/keyboard/vim.js#L3182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VimApi.defineOperator('delete', fn)` to change the delete function. But depending on what exactly you want to change there may be a better way too.